# Large file copy with GCD - Dispatch IO consumes large amounts of memory

Tags: ios, macos, memory-leaks, io, grand-central-dispatch

I'm transitioning a large file copy operation from `NSStream` to a dispatch IO implementation with GCD.

When copying two 1GB files together into a single 2GB file, the app consumes 2GB of memory with GCD. The `NSStream` implementation consumes just 50MB.

In Instruments, I can see `start_wqthread` calls allocating 1MB chunks, as I requested with my block size for the dispatch IO high water mark, but instead of being freed after being written to the output stream, they hang around.

How can I free the buffer after it has been written to the output stream?

If I create a completely new OS X Cocoa application in Xcode and paste the following code in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, it will consume 500-2000MB of memory. (To test, replace the temp file references with local file references.)

When creating a new project using the OS 10.9 SDK targeting OS 10.9, calls to `dispatch_release()` are forbidden by ARC. When targeting OS 10.6 in an older project, even with ARC enabled, calls to `dispatch_release()` are allowed but have no effect on the memory footprint.

```
NSArray* files = @[@"/1GBFile.tmp", @"/1GBFile2.tmp"];
NSString* outFile = @"/outFile.tmp";
NSString* queueName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.IO", [[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:(id)kCFBundleIdentifierKey]];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(queueName.UTF8String, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_io_t io_write = dispatch_io_create_with_path(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM, outFile.UTF8String, (O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND), (S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH), queue, NULL);
dispatch_io_set_high_water(io_write, 1024*1024);

[files enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* file, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    dispatch_io_t io_read = dispatch_io_create_with_path(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM, file.UTF8String, O_RDONLY, 0, queue, NULL);
    dispatch_io_set_high_water(io_read, 1024*1024);
    dispatch_io_read(io_read, 0, SIZE_MAX, queue, ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t data, int error) {
        if (error) {
            dispatch_io_close(io_write, 0);
            return;
        }

        if (data) {
            size_t bytesRead = dispatch_data_get_size(data);
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                dispatch_io_write(io_write, 0, data, queue, ^(bool doneWriting, dispatch_data_t dataToBeWritten, int errorWriting) {
                    if (errorWriting) {
                        dispatch_io_close(io_read, DISPATCH_IO_STOP);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        if (done) {
            dispatch_io_close(io_read, 0);
            if (files.count == (idx+1)) {
                dispatch_io_close(io_write, 0);
            }
        }
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've worked out a solution using a dispatch group.

The code essentially copies each file in sequence synchronously (blocking the loop from processing the next file until the previous file has been completely read and written), but allows the file reading and writing operations to be queued asynchronously.

I believe the memory over-consumption was due to the fact that reads for multiple files were being queued simultaneously. I would have thought that would be fine for a serial queue, but it seems blocking progress with a dispatch group, so that only work to read and write a single file is queued, does the trick. With the following code, peak memory usage is ~7MB.

Now, a single input file is queued to be read, each read operation queues its corresponding write operations, and the loop on the input files is blocked until all reading and writing operations are complete.

```
NSArray* files = @[@"/1GBFile.tmp", @"/1GBFile2.tmp"];
NSString* outFile = @"/outFile.tmp";
NSString* queueName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.IO", [[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:(id)kCFBundleIdentifierKey]];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(queueName.UTF8String, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_io_t io_write = dispatch_io_create_with_path(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM, outFile.UTF8String, (O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND), (S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH), queue, NULL);
dispatch_io_set_high_water(io_write, 1024*1024);

[files enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* file, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    if (*stop) {
        return;
    }
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    dispatch_io_t io_read = dispatch_io_create_with_path(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM, file.UTF8String, O_RDONLY, 0, queue, NULL);
    dispatch_io_set_high_water(io_read, 1024*1024);
    dispatch_io_read(io_read, 0, SIZE_MAX, queue, ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t data, int error) {
        if (error || *stop) {
            dispatch_io_close(io_write, 0);
            *stop = YES;
            return;
        }

        if (data) {
            size_t bytesRead = dispatch_data_get_size(data);
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                dispatch_group_enter(group);
                dispatch_io_write(io_write, 0, data, queue, ^(bool doneWriting, dispatch_data_t dataToBeWritten, int errorWriting) {
                    if (errorWriting || *stop) {
                        dispatch_io_close(io_read, DISPATCH_IO_STOP);
                        *stop = YES;
                        dispatch_group_leave(group);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (doneWriting) {
                        dispatch_group_leave(group);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        if (done) {
            dispatch_io_close(io_read, 0);
            if (files.count == (idx+1)) {
                dispatch_io_close(io_write, 0);
            }
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }
    });
}];
```

Comment: I was also thinking a sequential file operation might work better. I haven't tested the latest code, although is the time it takes about the same? I'm glad you found a solution; and since this is such a good example I've upvoted your question and answer. — best regards :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `[self cleanUpAndComplete];` is, however, it doesn't appear you ever call [dispatch_close](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW63) for the other channels you've created (*only* io_read).

— from [dispatch_create](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW74):

> The returned object is retained before it is returned; it is your
>   responsibility to close the channel and then release this object when
>   you are done using it.

Comment: You're right - I removed `[self cleanUpAndComplete]`, as it's irrelevant, and added a call to `dispatch_io_close(io_write, 0)` to make it more explicit, though it made no difference for the problem at hand. At the end of this function, the IO channel goes out of scope, the references to it should be released when writing is done, and the channel is automatically closed and cleaned up - "The channel closes the file descriptor and calls its cleanup handler when... All references to the channel are released."

Comment: @nekno, You'll need to use `dispatch_io_release()` after `dispatch_io_close`(which closes the file descriptor), although doesn't release what `dispatch_io_create` has allocated. At the very end you may also need a `dispatch_io_release(queue);`

Comment: Thanks - As you see, I already have the `dispatch_release()` calls in the cleanup handler for each channel. The cleanup handler is executed after channel errors or explicit calls to `dispatch_io_close()`.

Comment: I used your code mostly as it is now (making a few minor changes to the order of releasing) and the application never went over 6.6MB of memory consumption copying a 1.2GB file in < 20 seconds.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm still seeing the problem with a plain vanilla, brand new app. You can copy/paste my (edited) code above into a new Cocoa app in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method. If you change the paths for the input files to point to a couple large files, and the output file to change to a new file, I'm still seeing 500-2000MB memory in the Xcode memory profiler and Instruments.

Comment: @nekno, Is the main concern now the amount of ram it peaks to during the dispatch, or a matter of not releasing? The new code did consume 1.13GB at it's peak when I tried it, but after file merge operations completed it went down to 15.9MB. I'm wondering if perhaps a different approach to the file merge would be more efficient in terms of keeping ram usage down; it's something I would need to explore to know the answer — for a straight file append the dispatch method works great though.

Comment: My basic concern is peak memory usage, whatever the cause. At this point, I'm thinking that a few changes to calls won't suffice. As you said, a different approach would be more efficient, and right now, that seems to be the current `NSStream`-based approach.